# Pagination numbers not updating properly

Tags: jquery, pagination

Hey, I'm trying to get my pagination numbers to update when the user uses the filter options at the side of the page.

Here is what I'm working on: [Click Here](http://jsbin.com/ukoma3)

The problem is, when you click the color - Yellow - you should only get 1 result(Giant) and only 1 page number should display. however the pagination is not updating properly and still displays all page numbers.

**EDIT:**

I have placed the paginateIt() function at the end of the filter script but now I get an **unresponsive script warning**

I have updated the script with my recent changes below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function paginateIt(){
 //how much items per page to show
 var show_per_page = 3; 
 //getting the amount of elements inside content div
 var number_of_items = $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().size();

 //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
 var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

 //set the value of our hidden input fields
 $('#current_page').val(0);
 $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

 //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

 /* 
 what are we going to have in the navigation?
  - link to previous page
  - links to specific pages
  - link to next page
 */
 var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
 var current_link = 0;
 while(number_of_pages > current_link){
  navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
  current_link++;
 }
 navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

 $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

 //add active_page class to the first page link
 $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

 //hide all the elements inside content div
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().css('display', 'none');

 //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

// Start filter script
(function($) {

  $.fn.randomize = function(){
    return $(this).sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
  }

  $.fn.filterprojects = function(settings) {
    settings = $.extend({
      animationSpeed: 900,
      animationPulse: 100,
      animationEase: "linear",
      activeClass: "active",
      allTag: "all",
      randomize: true,
      show: { width: "show", opacity: "show" },
      hide: { width: "hide", opacity: "hide" },
      filterTagSelector: [] // specify at least one 
      }, settings);

      $(this).each(function(i, o){
        var _elements = $(this).children();

        /* Binding the filter */
        $(this).bind("filter", function(){
          var _groups = [];
          var _filtered_elements = _elements;
          $.each(settings.filterTagSelector, function(k, j){
            _groups[k] = [];
            $(this + "." + settings.activeClass).each(function(){ 
              if(!$(this).hasClass(settings.allTag) && this.hash != undefined) { _groups[k].push(this.hash.substring(1)); }
            });
            if(_groups[k].length > 0){
              _filtered_elements = _filtered_elements.filter("." + _groups[k].join(",.")); 
            }
          });

          /* Randomize */
          if(settings.randomize){
            _filtered_elements = _filtered_elements.randomize();
            _elements = _elements.randomize();
          }
          /* Show */
          _filtered_elements.each(function(i,o){
            $(this).queue(function(){
              $(this).animate({left: "+0"}, (settings.animationPulse*i)); // dirty trick :)
              $(this).animate(settings.show, settings.animationSpeed);
              $(this).dequeue()
            });
          });

          /* Hide */
          _elements.not(_filtered_elements).each(function(i,o){
            $(this).queue(function(){
              $(this).animate({left: "+0"}, (settings.animationPulse*i)); // dirty trick :)
              $(this).animate(settings.hide, settings.animationSpeed);
              $(this).dequeue()
            });
          });
        });
        /* Setup filter selectors */
        $.each(settings.filterTagSelector, function(k, j){
          $(""+this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass(settings.allTag)){
              $(j).removeClass(settings.activeClass);
              $(this).addClass(settings.activeClass);
            } else {
              $(this).hasClass(settings.activeClass) ? $(this).removeClass(settings.activeClass) : $(this).addClass(settings.activeClass);
              $(j+"."+settings.activeClass).length > 0 ? $(j+"."+settings.allTag).removeClass(settings.activeClass) : $(j+"."+settings.allTag).addClass(settings.activeClass);
            }
            /* Triggering the filter */ 
            $(o).trigger("filter");
          })
        });
      });
      return this
    };
})(jQuery); // End filter script
paginateIt();
} // End PaginateIt script
paginateIt();


}); // End of JS script.

function previous(){

 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
 //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}

function next(){
 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
 //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
 //get the number of items shown per page
 var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

 //get the element number where to start the slice from
 start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

 //get the element number where to end the slice
 end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

 //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

 /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
 and remove that class from previously active page link*/
 $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

 //update the current page input field
 $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `paginateIt` is responsible for rendering the page numbers below, shouldn't you call it every time a new filter is applied?

Comment: Yes, I have tried placing it within the filtering part but nothing seemed to work. I guess I put it in the wrong area. Any ideas of where it should go exactly?

Comment: Whenever you change which elements have the ".hidden" class, you have to refresh the entire pagination system.